# AVC denied warning leads to crash in android app

Tags: android, crash, logcat

I have an app which is crashing from time to time and the only reason for the crash I can thing of, has to be the following LogCat content (yep, two times the same line):

```
07-19 18:16:16.636 W/the.app: type=1400 audit(0.0:4418): avc: denied { read } for comm=4173796E635461736B202331 name="mem" dev="debugfs" ino=81636 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:debugfs:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
07-19 18:16:16.636 W/the.app: type=1400 audit(0.0:4419): avc: denied { read } for comm=4173796E635461736B202331 name="mem" dev="debugfs" ino=81636 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:debugfs:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
```

Followed by "Force finishing activity". The biggest "surprise" here is, that it is sometimes working totally fine, but more often not. I have no idea what I can do with those messages.

Device: Zuk Z2 Pro (rooted)

OS: Android 6.0.1 (ZUI 2.0)

Comment: Can you provide where you are experiencing the error: emulator/device model, os version, rooted/unrooted.

Comment: Zuk Z2 Pro, ZUI 2, Android 6.0.1, rooted

Comment: have you got the solution please post,  I had simmillar issue..!